# awk / sed to print only up to the underscore character

Tags: unix, bash-scripting, unix-utils

How can I use awk or sed to print a string only up to the first underscore character?

Before:

```
host100_044 2
host101_045 2
host102_046 2
```

After:

```
host100
host101
host102
```

Answer (score 24):

This can be done with `cut`:

```
cut -d _ -f 1
```

e.g.

```
$ echo host100_044 2 | cut -d _ -f 1
host100
```

Also with `awk` can be done with `awk -F_ '{print $1}'` (probably there is a cleaner way of doing that)

Comment: @Renan How do I modify this cut-function if I want the output to contain all the input information in addition to performing the cut?

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative for sed:

```
echo 'host100_044 2' | sed 's/^\(.*\)_.*$/\1/'
```

If you have these in a file, you could call it as follows;

```
cat fileName | sed 's/^\(.*\)_.*$/\1/'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
echo host100_044 2 host101_045 2 host102_046 2| sed 's/_/ /g' | awk 'BEGIN { RS="host"} {printf("host%s ", $1)}'  | cut -d ' ' -f2-
```

Output:

```
host100 host101 host102
```

With newlines:

```
echo host100_044 2 host101_045 2 host102_046 2| sed 's/_/ /g' | awk 'BEGIN { RS="host"} $1 ~ /[0-9]/ {print "host"$1}'
```

Output:

```
host100
host101
host102
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`:

```
echo host100_044 2 | sed 's;_.*;;'
```

Using `sed` in place edit option,

```
sed -i.old 's;_.*;;' infile
```

Comment: Was just writing the same, even though `awk` solution is already posted (and `cut` is probably best in this case), since he asked about `sed`, but you beat me with seconds :-) . You can even strip the `$`, since it will match `.*` to end of line by default.

Comment: @DanielAndersson: yes.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo "host100_044 2" | awk -F'_' '{print $1}'
host100
```

The `-F'_'` instructs `awk` to use underscores as field delimiters. The `awk` script itself just prints the first field.

Answer (score 0):

This will print the output before `_` :

`sed 's/_.*//' -filename`